# Simple Java program - Coding bat sumNumbers

Tags: java, strings, integer, modules

The problem is stated as follows:

> Given a string, return the sum of the numbers appearing in the string, ignoring all other characters. A number is a series of 1 or more digit chars in a row. (Note: Character.isDigit(char) tests if a char is one of the chars '0', '1', .. '9'. Integer.parseInt(string) converts a string to an int.)
>
> sumNumbers("abc123xyz") → 123
>
> sumNumbers("aa11b33") → 44
>
> sumNumbers("7 11") → 18

Here's the program I wrote based on `Character.isDigit(char)` and `Integer.parseInt(string)`.

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
          int count = 0;
          for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) {
              if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j))) count++;
              else break;
          }
          sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i + count));
          i += count;
      }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I'm not sure if I should make it more modular since it's pretty straightforward. I was wondering if I could do this without `count`. Also, I know it's nit-picky, but I want to know if the way I format my for loops and if else statements is good style. This is just a standalone program, so I'm not really concerned about the public/private issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know if the way I format my for loops and if else statements is good style.

On the whole, yeah, looks good.

I recommend you use braces for one-liner blocks as well. In this instance, I'm not batting an eye at it—it's fine—but it's a good habit to learn.

> I was wondering if I could do this without `count`.

Yes, since `count = j - i`, you can elide it.

```
int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
      int j;
      // start at i+1 because we know i has a digit
      for (j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j))) {
          break;
        }
      }
      sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j));
      i = j;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Alternatively, if the `break` is a bit of an eye-sore, you could hoist the check into the for-header, but I'm not 100% it's an improvement:

```
int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
      int j;
      // start at i+1 because we know i has a digit
      for (j = i + 1; j < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j)); j++);
      sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j));
      i = j;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

*Note:* `String.substring` creates a new string since Java 7—in the reference implementation, at least, and `String.toCharArray` creates a new object too. If you want to avoid these allocations, you can do the char-to-digit conversion manually, but it's a bit messier, easy to muck up, and I feel that's out of scope for the exercise.

Comment: I like you're answer the best because it answered my individual questions even though I think Oscar Smith had a great answer as well.

Comment: Also, the boolean condition in the second for loop is more of an eye sore to me. I find nothing wrong with `break`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things you can do here to make things simpler. The first is to make your inner loop a while loop instead of a for loop. With this idea, you  can build up each number char by char, using `Character.getNumericValue()` which will return `1` for `'1'` etc. With charVal, we can incrementally build up our number by multiplying the by 10 and adding the new digit. When we reach a non-digit, we add the current num to our sum, and set sum to 0. Since the code now only operates one char at a time, we don't need `i`, or `j` either. With these changes, your updated code is

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
    int sum = 0;
    int num = 0;
    for (char ch : exampleString.toCharArray()) {
        int digit = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        if (digit >= 0 && digit <= 9) {
            num = num * 10 + digit;
        } else {
            sum += num;
            num = 0;
        }
    }
    return sum + num;
}
```

Comment: How come you don’t initialize num to 1? And I think digit would be a better name.

Comment: You initialize `num` to 0, because the first time you see a `5` (eg), you want `num*10 + 5` to equal 5, which means num needs to start at 0. It also means that when you don't hit number characters, you can add `num` to `sum` without changing the answer.

Comment: You also have some typos like missing `;`'s and and an extra `)` but when I started testing your program, I get different results. Some tests are now failing. `sumNumbers("abc123xyz")` returns `0` instead of `123`.

Comment: I edited your code to fix the above test case but cases where the integer is the last value in the `String` such as `sumNumbers("7 11")` are returning the first integers like `7` but forgetting about the last one like `11`.

Comment: I just fixed the `sumNumbers("7 11")` case

Comment: That worked! But only for that case. My edit fixed other things, but you still need to make sure `digit <= 9` otherwise you fail on most test cases. Anyways, my code works, so thanks!

Comment: when can `digit` be greater than `9`?

Comment: I’m not sure but it fails the tests. Test it yourself. EDIT: It happens when the char is not a Unicode version of a digit between 0 and 9.

Comment: @OscarSmith Roman numerals, for instance, and the letters A through Z, as per the [method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and is short enough to be understood.

If you don't want to work on the level of individual characters, you can use regular expressions. Here is the code:

```
public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(str);
    int sum = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is not the fastest code, but I find it easy to read once you know that `[0-9]` means *a digit*, and the `+` means *1 or more times*.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my simple code for this one

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  String num = "";
  int total= 0;

  for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
        int pos = i;
        while(pos < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(pos))){
          pos++;

        }

         total += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i,pos));  
          i = pos;
    }


  }

  return total;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process. Please read [Why are alternative solutions not welcome?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8404/120114)